# Consider f(x, y) = a + bx + cy + dxy. Given a set of n data points where the i’th data point

Tags: statistics, least-squares

Consider $f(x, y) = a + bx + cy + dxy$. Given a set of n data points where the $i$’th data point is given by : $(x_{i} , y_{i} , z_{i})$, find the system of linear equations to solve for $a, b, c, d$ such that

(A) $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} (f(x_{i},y_{i}) -z_{i})^2$
 is minimized.
Solution Given as:

(B) MSE=$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(a+bx_{i}+cy_{i}+dx_{i}y_{i}-z_{i})^2$

$\frac{∂}{∂a}MSE(a,b,c,d)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(1)(a+bx_{i}+cy_{i}+dx_{i}y_{i}-z_{i})$

$\frac{∂}{∂a}MSE(a,b,c,d)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x)(a+bx_{i}+cy_{i}+dx_{i}y_{i}-z_{i})$

$\frac{∂}{∂a}MSE(a,b,c,d)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y)(a+bx_{i}+cy_{i}+dx_{i}y_{i}-z_{i})$

$\frac{∂}{∂a}MSE(a,b,c,d)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(xy)(a+bx_{i}+cy_{i}+dx_{i}y_{i}-z_{i})$

Can someone please explain a bit what is happening here ? Completely lost, if correctly remember correctly,it uses least squares method? How can we get step B from step A? Thank you advance.

provide a pic for avoid typos[image].

Comment: It seems that there is some typo in the solution. The partial derivatives should be with respect to $a, b, c$ and $d$, i.e., $\partial MSE(a, b,c, d)/\partial a$, $\partial MSE(a, b,c, d)/\partial b$, $\partial MSE(a, b,c, d)/\partial c$, and $\partial MSE(a, b,c, d)/\partial d$. In addition, all the $1/n$ should be $1/(2n)$ and the first paramthesis term after the summation sign should be $(1), (x_i), (y_i)$ and $(x_i y_i)$, in the respective equations.

Comment: Also, just write out explicitly $f(x_i, y_i)$ in (A), from the first formula